# Как писать к дню или ко дню

Tags: орфография

Предложение:
«К(о) Дню космонавтики приурочена выставка рисунков «К далёким звёздам!»

Answer (score 1):

**к — ко**

**Добавление гласного о к предлогу к наблюдается в следующих случаях: 1) перед односложными словами, начинающимися со стечения согласных, например: ко дну (ср. к дневнику), ко сну (ср. к сновидениям), ко мне (ср. к мнимой величине), ко лбу; также: ко многому, ко многим; 2) перед словами весь, всякий: ко всему, ко всякому; 3) в отдельных выражениях: ко двору, не ко двору (быть, прийтись).**

*Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь.*

Как видите, строгого правила на этот счёт нет. В Нацкорпусе КО ДНЮ - 724 документа, 867 вхождений, К ДНЮ - 142 документа, 165 вхождений.

*КО ДНЮ КОСМОНАВТИКИ* - предпочтительный вариант, но и *К ДНЮ КОСМОНАВТИКИ* звучит по крайней мере привычно.

***Примеры из НКРЯ***: Про Минца не сочиняют очерков к Дню рационализатора. [Сергей Довлатов. Чемодан (1986)]

*Вот так глобус крутит и говорит: этот город, говорит, узять к Октяберьской годовщине, а этот, говорит, ко дню Красной Армии.* [Владимир Войнович. Монументальная пропаганда // «Знамя», 2000]